# Trying to reset data when return to the page

Tags: reactjs, native

I am trying to reset data when return to the page

here is my piece of code

```
    componentDidMount(){
        
        this.checkIfAlreadyLoggedIn();
        
        this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',
            () => {
                this.setState({products:[],alreadyLoadedCount:0});
                this.checkIfAlreadyLoggedIn();
            }
          );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.willFocusSubscription();
    }
```

the page is perfectly reload but the problem is when i back to the previous page the follwing error shows

```
 ERROR  TypeError: this.willFocusSubscription is not a function. (In 'this.willFocusSubscription()', 'this.willFocusSubscription' is an instance of Object)
```

i put the above code in the previous page also. but the error shows same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed willfocus to didfocus and and remove it componentWillUnMount . it is worked

```
componentDidMount() {
   
....

 this.focusListener= this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'didFocus',
            () => {
                this.setState({products:[],alreadyLoadedCount:0});
                // loading page code
            }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.focusListener.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change '**willFocus**' to '**focus**' as show in the image below and check
[image]

Comment: I changed willfocus to didfocus and it is worked.